# jQuery Draggable: Image Flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, draggable

I've been developing an Image panning tool, and after a kind member directed me to the draggable plugin for jQuery, I have most of it completed.  Right now if the user drags the image (contained inside a div of about 300px by 300px), the image will first flicker, then pan.  This problems seems to occur after a mouse down event, on the mouse move event.  The image will shift into one of the four corners on mouse move, and moving to certain areas will cause another shift.  I haven't been able to find anything through google, and I'm relatively new to jQuery still.

I've uploaded the code here, in case my description is too vague:
http://www.studentgroups.ucla.edu/csa/test/zoom.htm

Any ideas or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For one, you've made the image draggable both via the jQuery plugin, and your own code. Your code is changing the `background-position` of the `div`, and the jQuery plugin is changing the `div`'s actual position. That's bound to cause some problems.

Also, Draggable's `containment` parameter seems to be designed for draggable items who are smaller than their parent container, not ones who are bigger, like you're trying to do.

Anyways, here's the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable().bind('dragstop', function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.position.top > 0) {
            $(this).css('top', 0);
        }
        if (ui.position.left > 0) {
            $(this).css('left', 0);
        }

        var bottom = -($(this).height() - $(this).parent().height()),
        right  = -($(this).width() - $(this).parent().width());

        if (ui.position.top < bottom) {
            $(this).css('top', bottom);
        }
        if (ui.position.left < right) {
            $(this).css('left', right);
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't need edge-snapping, you can get rid of the `.bind()` function, and just call `.draggable()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't realize that -_-
I was writing this from scratch yesterday, until someone pointed out I could just use the draggable plugin.  I guess I forgot to remove my code, FML

Thank you so much for your help!  I do have one more question though;  what does the 'ui' refer to?

Comment: No problem :). `ui` is sort of like the event object (`e`), but it contains jQuery UI-specific stuff. See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable